# Ckeditor Invalid server response in file upload

Tags: ckeditor

I updated ckeditor from version 3 to 4.16.12. I have a custom upload.php, which still works for images, but for PDFs and other allowed file types it gives "Incorrect server response."  The error message is described as "Text could not be parsed to JSON."  I can't find any description of what parameters are expected.  My original code was returning:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, '$url', '$message')</script>";
```

As I guess I tried updating to

```
$return_data = array(
    'url' => $url,
    'message' => $message );
echo json_encode( $return_data );
```

and then

```
$return_data = array(
    'funcNum' => $funcNum'],
    'url' => $url,
    'message' => $message );
echo json_encode( $return_data );
```

In either case, when I return the JSON data, an alert box pops up that says "undefined".

What am I doing wrong?  How should I change upload.php for uploading files in version 4?

- EDIT *
  I discovered a YouTube video that suggested I should use

  $return_data = array( 'file_name'=> $url );
  echo json_encode( $return_data );

That gave the same result - "undefined" in a popup box.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in an example from another Stackoverflow post.  The correct data to return is:

```
$return_data = array( 'fileName' => $new_name, 'uploaded' => true, 'url' => $url );
echo json_encode( $return_data );
```

And this works for both images and other file types, like PDFs.